# Can virus transmit over remote desktop?

Tags: desktop, virus

I am using Windows XP to access another Windows XP via Remote Desktop. I suspect that the remote one has a virus. Is it possible the virus will affect my host computer?

Comment: Yes. But this question is off-topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided you're not using an account that has a login script to map shared drives, or transferring files between the two, I doubt you'd have a problem with it.

Comment: is this true? Virus transmission via RD is extremely unlikely.But if you have some of the options in the Remote Desktop client turned on, like shared drives (under "More" on the "Shared Resources" tab), then it's possible. At that point, you've got a virtual network share via your RDP session and network shares are vulnerable to virus transmission.If the infected file is on the remote desktop machine's HDD then some files on the Hard Disk Drive may be infected also.So be careful if making file transfers.It will not infect your local machine if you don't make any file transfers.